# how to return a json string in php for using it in java

Tags: java, php, android, json

I want wrote an API in php for using it in my android app. In the php side I do this for return info in an array

`echo json_encode($array)`

result of this code is like this, see online result [in this link](http://mtg1376.gigfa.com/api/food?day=All):

```
{"value":[{"id":"1","name":"kufta","meal":"1","photo_id":"","explanation":"xoshmazas","foodtime":"0000-00-0000:00:00"},{"id":"2","name":"\r\nAsh","meal":"2","photo_id":"","explanation":"sdfdsfsdfdsfdsfsdf","foodtime":"2017-06-26 14:00:00"},{"id":"3","name":"kabab","meal":"3","photo_id":"","explanation":"kabab kheili khoshmaze ast","foodtime":"2017-06-29 00:00:00"}]}
```

but in java side when I load this, app crash but when I use this json string [in this site](http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/). Android app works fine

my java code for reading the url content

```
public class WebService {

    private String connectToServer(String address, String requestMethod) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(address);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(requestMethod);
            return inputStreamToString(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String inputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String nextLine;
            while ((nextLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(nextLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
  line 23 : public  List<FoodModel> getFoods(){ <-----------Error is here
        String response = connectToServer("http://mtg1376.gigfa.com/api/food?day=All","GET");
        if(response != null){
            List<FoodModel> foodList = new ArrayList<);
            try{
                JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray foodArray = mainObject.getJSONArray("value");
                for(int i = 0 ; i< foodArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject foodObject = foodArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    FoodModel foodModel = new FoodModel();
                    foodModel.id = foodObject.getString("id");
                    foodModel.name = foodObject.getString("name");
                    foodModel.meal = foodObject.getString("meal");
                    foodModel.photo_id = foodObject.getString("photo_id");
                    foodModel.explanation = foodObject.getString("explanation");
                    foodModel.foodtime=foodObject.getString("foodtime");
                    foodList.add(foodModel);
                }
                return foodList;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null; }


}
```

java error log : https://ibb.co/hQneXk

whats the problem?

Comment: Please share your crash log.

Comment: I cannot see it now, but I've a GOOD advice for you. If you are trying to use JSON in java, just use GSON. It's a quasi-magical library made by google that builds objects (like your 'foodModel') from / to JSON in one line... Take a look here:http://www.javacreed.com/simple-gson-example/

Comment: @AndyDeveloper see [this link](https://ibb.co/hQneXk) for error log

Comment: It looks like your list is null what is on line number 55 and 23?

Comment: @AndyDeveloper I update code and added line 23 please check

Comment: what about 55 line? What are you doing inside line 23?